# How to pass CollectionView object to custom control in .NET Maui?

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-6.0, maui

I'm trying to leverage a custom control within a CollectionView and would like to pass the entire object of the particular CollectionView ItemTemplate into my custom control.

Here's my xaml page:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding WorkOps}" SelectionMode="None" ItemsLayout="VerticalList">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="75" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="15" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Column="0" 
                    Text="{Binding OpType}" 
                    FontSize="Caption" 
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1" 
                    Text="{Binding OpNumber}" 
                    FontSize="Caption" 
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="2" 
                    Text="{Binding Instructions}" 
                    FontSize="Body"/>

                <Entry Grid.Column="2" 
                    Grid.Row="1" 
                    Text="{Binding Measure}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsSimpleMeasure}" />

                <root:TableMeasureView Grid.Column="2" 
                                    Grid.Row="1" 
                                    Op="{Binding .}" 
                                    IsVisible="{Binding IsTableMeasure}" />

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

and here is my custom control I'm trying to implement:

```
public class TableMeasureView : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty WorkOpProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Op), typeof(WorkOp), typeof(ContentPage));

    public WorkOp Op
    {
        get { return (WorkOp)GetValue(WorkOpProperty); }
        set { SetValue(WorkOpProperty, value); }
    }

    public TableMeasureView()
    {
    }

    // ...
}
```

I get the following message when trying to build:

> XamlC error XFC0009: No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Op", or mismatching type between value and property.

Is what I'm attempting possible?

Comment: Should be possible. Have you tried to use `object` instead of `WorkOp` in your custom control just to ensure that the XAML binding and BindableProperty are correct?  Also might want to double-check if `ContentPage` in `BindableProperty.Create` should instead be `MainPage`.

Comment: @James - right, the binding expects `object`. I was writing a full answer while you made that comment. :) Re "MainPage": To clarify, you mean "the class name of that page". (Though AFAIK, it will work fine as is.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. What's happening is that the xaml doesn't attempt to figure out that the type of `{Binding .}` is `WorkOp`. It wants a property of type `object`.

The fix is to give it a property of type `object`. Then for convenient access in your custom control, make a second property that casts that to `WorkOp`:

```cs
public static readonly BindableProperty WorkOpProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Op), typeof(object), typeof(ContentPage));

public object Op
{
    get { return GetValue(WorkOpProperty); }
    set { SetValue(WorkOpProperty, value); }
}

private WorkOp TypedOp => (WorkOp)Op;
```

NOTE: Change `Op` and `TypedOp` above to whatever names you like. If you change `Op`, remember to also change in the xaml that refers to it.